# Shortest path ( destination = origin )

Tags: algorithm, graph, neural-network, shortest-path

> What algorithm can I apply to find the shortest path from a node,
>   throw all the other nodes and return to origin ?

[image: graph]

Comment: Is the graph directed or undirected? Can a node be visited more than once?

Comment: Is undirected and a node can be visited only once

Answer (score 0):

This link has C# `( exact optimal solution )` implementation of Held–Karp algorithm that solves the problem in time O ( n^2 2^n ) :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762581/Held-Karp-algorithm-implementation-in-Csharp

Answer (score 0):

I researched this situation for a while now, I did not find many solutions, making me wonder as I'd imagine this being a general need but apparently isn't.

So here is what I came up with, I'd appreciate if whoever comments or edits it, so we can improve this.

> Let's say we have 10 locations, we'll first generate all possible
> combinations of pairs between all those 10 locations:

1. location 1 > location 2
2. location 1 > location 3
3. location 1 > location 4
   ... till 10

....skip location 2 > location 1, as pair already exist at 1 > 2, we can reuse location pairs in both ways

11. location 2 > location 3
12. location 2 > location 4
    ... till 10

. . ...

20. location 3 > 4
21. location 3 > 5
    ...

> Now once we have all combined pairs, let's generate all possible
> routes, with each route we'll save the total duration:

1. Pair 3, Pair 35 (location 4 > 7), Pair 51 (7 > 3) ....., Pair 41 (6 > 1) - the last one must be a pair that includes the origin, as that is the final destination.
2. ...different combination of location pairs...
3. ...till we have all possible routes

> Having a list of all possible routes, and each route containing its total
> duration, you can now select the route that has the shortest duration.